# Will the relocated Tsukiji have a larger auction and market areas?

Tags: japan, tokyo

Last time I went to [Tsukiji fish market](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3021.html) I couldn't get into the auction area, despite trying three times at an ungodly hour. I did however enjoy the outer market. Tsukiji will be [relocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsukiji_fish_market#Planned_relocation_to_Toyosu) to [Toyosu](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3013.html) in November but I couldn't find any maps or proposed plans for the new layout.

Will the auction areas be larger and (presumably) more accessible ? Will the outer market be enlarged or at least preserved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Tuna Auctions

While we know the auction area will be bigger (as will all buildings be), it's unclear whether it will be more accessible to visitors.

The sources I found claimed there would be a viewing area above the auction area which could enable visitors to see it from above. Considering the move's emphasis on hygiene and safety, this is quite likely as it clearly separates the professionals from the tourists.

As can be seen on [Tsukiji Market's website](http://www.tsukiji-market.jp/events/categories/toyosu-tuna-auction/), there will be paying tours of the auction area. Perhaps that means there will no longer be an auction viewing?

**Considering the contradictory sources, the only sure way to know is to wait for the market to open on November 7th.**

---

### Outer Market

The Outer Market in Tsukiji will be preserved in hopes of maintaining a strong tourist presence. Keep in mind that it will most likely not be the same as before since the inner market will lose lots of it's appeal by closing down. There should still be some very interesting sightseeing to be had nonetheless.

A new "Outer Market" will be established in Toyosu in one of the three buildings. Sadly, it will not be the organic aggregation of shops that formed around Tsukiji as the area is much more regulated and planned. Visitors will still be able to shop around however as many of the inner market shops will be moving to this building, including blacksmiths, sushi restaurants and other shops.

---

Here are some links that discuss the subject:

https://foodsaketokyo.com/2016/06/21/need-to-know-tsukiji-move-to-toyosu/
http://mainichi.jp/english/articles/20160730/p2a/00m/0na/010000c